# Re: Samsung MultiFunc M2875FD - Repeating Horizontal Lines Every 7.8cm

Tags: laser-printer, multi-function-printer

This combo printer scanner fax machine was printing flawlessly 1 year ago. I put this printer in its box and stored it for 1 year. Then I connected it to the computer and printed.

EVERY page has the same horizontal bars across the entire page. The height of the lines is about 1.5 to 2 millimeters. Samsung, as usual, provides very little information about what might be causing this.

I have seen some commentators state that this could be caused by a roller.  I do not want to buy a new cartridge because this one has printed only about 30 pages.

What is the cause of this, would repeated tipping of the toner cartridge be helpful?

Comment: `... could be caused by a roller.` +1 on that. Open it up as much as possible and clean the rubber rollers that feed the paper.

Comment: As the spacing is 7.8cm, the diameter of the problem roller is about 2.5cm. I would suspect the fuser, but have a look through the printer for a roller with that diameter. Note that in many printers the cartridge has a "roller" built-in (the drum) which is normally hidden under a flap. It would help if you could post a sample print.

Comment: I found the user manual. It lists the fuser and the cartridge as possible problems. See page 290 in this PDF: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/447905/Samsung-Sl-M2875fd.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions posted here, so far.  I now see how I might potentially try to clean the cartridge components, and test to see if the problem has resolved.
The repeating horizontal lines mean a rotating part, but I did not know where to look.

Comment: Does the Samsung software not provide cleaning options?